# Hideous Laughter while climbing

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, combat, falling, prone

I found [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/94193) about [hideous laughter](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/hideous-laughter/) being casted on someone who is flying. James Jacob’s answer in the exchange is more geared to what happens when a character who’s flying is knocked prone (spoiler: they don’t).

My question is for when it’s cast on someone when they‘re *climbing*.

The spell says *fall prone*, but it doesn’t say anything about them releasing their grip from what they’re holding (e.g. a ladder like what my PC in my campaign is climbing). Maybe I’m being pedantic but common sense would rule that, if they fall prone, they fall from whatever height they were at. No? Yes?

Answer (score 2):

## The linked quote already addresses this

It's not just flying creatures who can't be knocked prone.  Climbing creatures can't be either:

> You can mess with a creature in the ways detailed in the Fly skill, which might make them fall, but you can't make a flying creature prone. Or a swimming or burrowing **or climbing creature**, for that matter.

emphasis added.

It's not just the title line of FAQ answers that is errata, the whole passage carries that weight.